# JS function calling

Tags: javascript

I'm starting in JS and have been having trouble with a particular function I'm trying to write. The purpose is to have the text change once the button is pressed. The "nothing" text should change into "You say hi, I say Hey?" With the Hey? being text already on the document.

Here's the code, any pointers would be welcome!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript test </title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="hey">Hey?</p>
<p id ="nothing">Nothing</p>
<INPUT type =button VALUE="Button?" OnClick=(take())>

<script>
function take(){
var hey=document.getElementById("hey");
var nothing =document.getElementById("one");

nothing.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You say hi, I say " + hey));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Alright, thanks for all the help guys. No one in particular was 100% right but i tried a combination of all the suggestions and got about 99% of the way to where i wanted to go. My code looks like this now. The last change im trying to make is not to append new text strings but to replace the old string with the string that is currently being appended.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript test </title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="hey">Hey?</p>
<p id ="nothing">Nothing</p>
<input type ="button" value="Button?" OnClick="take();"/>

<script>
function take(){
var hey=document.getElementById("hey");
var nothing =document.getElementById("nothing");

nothing.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You say hi, I say " + hey.innerHTML));

}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I appreciate the help, thank you Stack Overflow community!

Comment: So you want to add "You Say Hi, I say hey" after nothing? Why do you get the "hey" element?

Comment: You might want to look into jQuery. It's easier to do things like this with it.

Comment: @woz i would not consider this worthy of the overhead from jQuery, but that's just me

Comment: I'd like the "nothing" text to turn into "You say hi, i say hey". I get the Hey element to get the text variable but im not sure how to put the variable into the line... 

nothing.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You say hi, I say Hey"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has a few issues.

First, you should specify `type="text/javascript"` on your script tag.

Second, your input should look like this:

```
<input id="button" type="button" value="Button?" />
```

Third, you should bind your event handler in the script tag (See [SoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_and_JavaScript)):

```
document.getElementById('button').onclick = take;
```

Fourth, your function looks for an element with id `one`, which does not exist. Did you mean id `nothing` instead?

Fifth, assuming you use the correct id to get the `nothing` element, you need to use the value from the other `p` when setting the value.

```
var take = function () {
    var hey = document.getElementById('hey');
    var nothing = document.getElementById('nothing');

    nothing.innerHTML= 'You say hi, I say ' + hey.innerHTML;
};
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/M5UWn/

As a side note, I found [jQFundamentals](http://jqfundamentals.com/) an excellent learning site for both jQuery and native javascript.

Comment: I've found tutorials similar to JQFundamentals for HTML and CSS but couldnt find one for JS. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0):

Change your input to this

```
<input type=button value="Button?" onclick="take();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript test </title>
</head>

<body>

<p id="hey">Hey?</p>
<p id ="nothing">Nothing</p>
<input type="button" value="Button?" onClick="take()"/>

<script>
function take(){
var hey=document.getElementById("hey");
var nothing =document.getElementById("nothing");

nothing.appendChild(document.createTextNode("You say hi, I say "+hey.value));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed 
the ending of input tag
added quotes to type of input and OnClick
you were doing `document.getElementById("one")` and there is no element with id `one`. So changed that to `nothing`

Comment: please explain the fixes you made so people don't have to do a string comparison to find what you did.

Comment: This is still not valid html, there is no closing input tag plus it really should be lowercase `input`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers here:

Change your button input html to look like this:

```
<INPUT type="button" VALUE="Button?" OnClick="take()">
```

Notice that all attributes are in double quotes.  Also, the extra parentheses around the function call are removed.

When you get the 'nothing' element, you're using the wrong id.  It should be like this:

```
var nothing = document.getElementById("nothing");
```

To change the text, it's simpler to just use this code:

```
nothing.innerText = "You say hi, I say " + hey.innerText;
```